# Strange error behavior after error handling finished

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, excel-2013

I am using a sub that creates unique sheet names by trying a name and redirecting the errors until a valid name is found.

The sub works, but after exiting the sub, and trying to test the value in a oleobject checkbox, it gives me the error that I was previously redirecting--that is unless I perform some other call such as `ws.Activate` or `application.screenupdating = false`. I have tried placing `Err.Clear` at various points in the code with no success.

I'm pretty new to VBA (less than a month using it) so forgive me for obvious mistakes.

I'm using excel 2013.

Run this first to create the checkbox in Sheet1 and make a new sheet with a specified name:

```
Private Sub runfirst()

    Dim cb1 As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheet1.OLEObjects.Delete
    Set cb1 = Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
    cb1.Name = "CheckBox1"
    cb1.Object.Caption = "Checkbox1"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    ws.Name = "mysheet"

End Sub
```

Main code:

```
Private Sub test1()
    'This throws an error
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    NameWS rootname:="mysheet", ws:=ws
    'ws.Activate
    If Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then MsgBox "true" Else MsgBox "false"

End Sub

Private Sub test2()
    ' This works fine
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    NameWS rootname:="mysheet", ws:=ws
    ws.Activate
    If Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then MsgBox "true" Else MsgBox "false"

End Sub


Private Sub NameWS(rootname As String, ws As Worksheet)
    ' This sub tries to name the WS as rootname, if it fails, it increments a counter in the name.

    Dim ctr As Long
    ctr = 0

    On Error GoTo Err1:
    ws.Name = rootname
    Exit Sub

BaseNameTaken:
    ctr = ctr + 1
    On Error GoTo Err1:
    ws.Name = rootname & " (" & ctr & ")"
    ' If execution makes it to here it means that a valid name has been found

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Err1:
    If ctr > 99 Then Resume Fail ' Just to ensure we haven't created an infinite loop
    Resume BaseNameTaken

Fail:
    ' Leave sub. Inability to name WS is not a critical error.
    MsgBox "Failed to name worksheet after " & ctr & " tries. Excel default name used."

End Sub
```

Comment: What error is it giving you? I just tested. And if I ran the first procedure first, and then ran Test1 it worked fine as long as NameWS was in the same module.

Comment: I get runtime error 1004: "That name is already taken. Try a different one." This is the error that I am redirecting in the NameWS function. I just tried it on my home computer (before I was at work) and I get the same error so it is reproducible for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a matter of setting `Application.DisplayAlerts`

you may want to use this function

```
Private Sub NameWS(rootname As String, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim ctr As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.name = rootname & IIf(ctr = 0, "", " (" & ctr & ")")
        ctr = ctr + 1
    Loop While Err > 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

furthermore, the line:

```
If Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then MsgBox "true" Else MsgBox "false"
```

can be simplified to:

```
MsgBox Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value
```

Comment: Very concise. This one works perfectly. My only question is why. I would like to understand why setting `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` makes it go away. And why, when I click Debug on the error it takes me to that if statement.

Comment: I mean, your loop only quits once there is no error, so why does it raise the error in a subsequent line (if I comment out the `Application.DisplayAlerts` lines)?

Comment: that latter is an _alert_ and not an _error_, i.e. [something](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx) you'd normally be aware of and respond accordingly to, but that you can really skip by suppressing the alert and thus ignoring it. There are some other occurrences where it's useful (follow the above link to get a few of them). Finally, you may want to accept this answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you!

Comment: I understand that. I use `Application.DisplayAlerts` in another part of my program to suppress the confirmation dialog from closing a sheet. But Excel is throwing an _error_ 1004 and it doesn't allow me to continue. How is that an _alert_? Is this just a bug in Excel?

Comment: If you remove `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` you'll see that your macro actually _has worked_ (you'll find the new worksheet named appropiately) while its execution has been temporarily stopped till you choose to press "End" or "Debug" in the message box displayed. I wouldn't say it's a bug since I don't have enough knowledge of Excel inner things

Comment: "If you remove `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` you'll see that your macro actually has worked" -- Hence my consternation, the error appears after the sub that is generating the error (which is being handled) has successfully completed. A seemingly unrelated line of code causes the error to actually be raised.

Comment: _"A seemingly unrelated line of code causes the error to actually be raised. "_: which is that "unrelated line"?

Comment: The error doesn't happen until I try to access that OLE object. I can execute other code just fine. For example if I replace the if-statement in `test1` with `ws.Range("A1").Value = "foo"` there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like `On Error Goto Label`. I find code that jumps about difficult to understand and difficult to get right.

The macro below is how I would code such as routine.

First, a few points that may help.

I have a folder named Resources with sub-folders "VBA", "VBA Excel" and "VBA Outlook".  If I used VBA Word or VBA Access I would have sub-folders for them as well. Whenever I have finished a development, I look through my code for routines that I might use again.  If the routine is general VBA, it is saved as a text file in "VBA". With your routine, I will save it as " NameWS .txt" within folder “VBA Excel”.

The macro starts with an explanation of what it does.  If the macro was complicated it would also have an overview of how it achieved its objective.  This helps me when I look at the macro in six or twelve months or five years.  I have macros that I wrote years ago and a quick look tells me if it will be helpful for today’s problem.

Lastly, there is the first line of the macro’s history.  Each time I update the macro, I will add a sentence or two saying what and why.

```
Private Sub NameWS(rootname As String, ws As Worksheet)

  ' Attempt to rename worksheet ws as rootname. If successful, exit.
  ' If unsuccessful, rename worksheet as rootname (N) where
  ' N is the first number in the sequence 1, 2, 3 and so on such
  ' that rootname (N) did not previously exist.

  '  7Nov16  Coded.

  Dim ctr As Long
  Dim NameCrnt As String

  ' Try rootname first
  On Error Resume Next
  ws.Name = rootname
  On Error GoTo 0
  If ws.Name = rootname Then
    ' Rename successful
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' rootnamne is use. Try rootname (1), rootname(2), etc, until
  ' get successful rename.
  ctr = 1
  Do While True
    NameCrnt = rootname & " (" & ctr & ")"
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Name = NameCrnt
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws.Name = NameCrnt Then
      ' Rename successful
      Exit Sub
    End If
    ctr = ctr + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I still get the same error from this one when I run from my sub `test1`. Were you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: @BenP.  I did not read your question carefully enough. I saw the problem with subroutine NameWS and fixed that. I did not appreciate the real problem was the later error with `Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value`. The temporary suppression of Excel standard error handling is sometimes the only technique for dealing with statements that might fail. It would be possible to code a version of NameWS that did not generate errors; it might be slow but it would work. But there are other statements for which the temporary suppression of Excel standard error handling is the only option.

Comment: I have never seen an error like this. I do not understand why playing with `DisplayAlerts` helps because this is not an alert. `Err.Clear` and `Err.Number = 0` do not help.  Something about an old error is retained. It can be cleared with WS.Activate or playing with `DisplayAlerts`.  I cannot find a “ordinary” statement that will clear this error. Is this problem unique to OLEObject? I do not know. Perhaps we should not worry too much since this problem would be picked up during routine testing and has a workaround.